# in_app_purchase Package flutter

Tags: flutter

I use in_app_purchase: ^0.2.1 Package for flutter. When I start the purchase I get this Error:

Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Unable to find explicit activity class {com.www.x.xx/com.android.billingclient.api.ProxyBillingActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?, null)

The Activity isnt defined in the manifest..

https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase#-readme-tab-

This is the Plugin!

Comment: E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/in_app_purchase(20957): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.www.x.xx/com.android.billingclient.api.ProxyBillingActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Can you show us your manifest file?

Comment: My permissions :                                                                             <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

Comment: <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="xx"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

Comment: <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



        <meta-data
            android:name="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            />

    </application>

Comment: How can I present this more neatly?

Comment: I get the same error with this PlugIn : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inapp_purchase#migration-guide

Comment: You can edit the original question and add the manifest there. Has the app been published?

Answer (score 1):

I have used Flutter Clean and now it works I dont know why.